# Physical examples of log CFTs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

There are examples of CFTs having correlators with logarithms. What are the examples of physical systems exhibiting such logarithmic behaviour (particularly in $d>2$ dimensions)?

Comment: Do you mean specifically logarithmic CFTs, used for e.g. the description of percolation, or are logarithmic corrections to power law behavior also fine?

Comment: I meant logarithmic CFTs. But to be honest I don't quite understand why *conformal* theories would allowed to have log terms in correlators, in the first place.

Comment: You might already know it, but here is a comprehensive reference for logarithmic CFTs in $d > 2$: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03959

Comment: Yes, I have seen this paper. But I was mainly interested in applications of LCFTs in physical systems.